# Converting svn patching system to git

Tags: database, git, svn, version-control, auto-update

My team maintain a large piece of software based on PHP/MySQL which currently uses svn for version control.

I'm now porting it to git, but this poses an issue with our update process which I'm not sure how to solve.

Our project has an auto-update program that updates the local install to the latest version from the svn repository, it basically uses `svn update` plus some other irrelevant operations. I've already ported this to `git pull` etc, that was the easy part.

The difficulty is in our database structure/data patching.

Right now if a dev needs to update the database schema, or perform any sort of operation on an existing database to bring it up to date, they create a patch file. This patch file is numbered manually at the time of committing, inline with what the *next* svn revision number will be. So if I'm committing an update that has a patch, I check the svn log for the last revision number, say 104, and I name my patch 'patch_105'. The auto-update program then runs `svn update`, and applies any patches it finds which are newer than the last installed version.

The flow looks like this:

1. Current revision: 100
2. Press update
3. Latest codebase version 105 pulled from svn
4. Check for patches newer than revision 100
5. Run patch_102, patch_105
6. Current revision is now 105

Moving to git now poses a problem, as git doesn't work off of revision numbers, so a sequential patching system can't work in this way. I know we can get the build number roughly by running `git rev-list --count HEAD`, but working with branches etc means I'm not sure there is any guarantee of what the next build number might be.

We could name the patch files by their commit hash perhaps, but then the updater doesn't have an easy read on the sequence of patches and what needs to be applied between 2 different versions. We could store what has already been run perhaps, but the patches often need to be run in order that they were committed so this is probably also insufficient.

So in summary, do you have an update process similar to this in your project? If so how are you handling this problem? Should I be thinking about this in a totally different way?

Thanks!

Comment: You are limiting yourself to the assumption that your database patching system needs to be tied in to your version control system the way it always has. I think you can probably design a better system with less headaches if you remove that constraint. For example, simply store the last script run in the database itself, and run anything newer.

Comment: I have a feeling I am but I'm finding it hard to get perspective after spending so long with svn! Any tips on how to name/store the patches?

Comment: This article might provide some additional perspective. https://martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html